# What are those non-glass/non-transparent window called? just wooden doors for windows?

Tags: word-choice

Do you guys know what those windows (like the ones on medieval castles) are called?  They are non-glass, non-transparent, wooden-doors pretty much; in other words, there are wooden doors on the opening of the wall... I've been looking around for awhile, but can't find the word.

The picture is [here](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.canstockphoto.com%2Fcastle-windows-and-wooden-shutters-39768589.html&psig=AOvVaw2mrXDr16PCpve3nAXxoBhe&ust=1619956690458000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCPiVh5C3qPACFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD)
Thanks for taking the time to assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!  It's called "Wooden Shutters".  :)  Thanks